# Laravel 5.2 NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and caffeinated Modules and I'm getting this error

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

I only get this error when I upload to my server but on my localhost I don't get an error.

I've also noticed that on my localhost I get all my routes listed but on my server I only have the home page.

My Users Module route.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function()
{
    Route::get('admin/', [
        'uses' => 'UsersController@showLogin',
        'as' => 'login'
    ]);

    Route::post('admin/', [
        'uses' => 'UsersController@doLogin',
        'as' => 'doLogin'
    ]);
});
```

and my Users Module UsersController.php

```
<?php

    namespace App\Modules\Users\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class UsersController extends Controller
    {
        public function showLogin(){
            echo "Users Controller";
        }
    }
```

If there is anything I've missed to help with this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This error generally shown when you access a url which is not defined in your route file. Recheck the url you are trying to access.

Your code doesn't seem to have any special error.

Add a `doLogin` method in your `UsersController`.

Besides, you can try by removing `/` from the route path.
I mean change this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function()
{
    Route::get('admin/', [
        'uses' => 'UsersController@showLogin',
        'as' => 'login'
    ]);

    Route::post('admin/', [
        'uses' => 'UsersController@doLogin',
        'as' => 'doLogin'
    ]);
});
```

to this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function()
{
    Route::get('admin', [
        'uses' => 'UsersController@showLogin',
        'as' => 'login'
    ]);

    Route::post('admin', [
        'uses' => 'UsersController@doLogin',
        'as' => 'doLogin'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: I still get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. I had to delete the /storage/app/modules.json and then I ran

```
php artisan module:optimize
```